# What happens if you throw a magical creature through an antimagic field?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, summoning, antimagic-field

Inspired by [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/128599/51849).

I have this idea. Take a creature that would be suppressed by the antimagic field, like an elemental or a celestial from *conjure celestial*. Since the spells creating one of those aren't instantaneous, [the creature would be affected by the antimagic field](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133615/what-creatures-does-antimagic-field-temporarily-wink-out-of-existence). Then throw it through the field. What happens?

**Will it fly through the field and appear on the other side or stop in the field?**

These are the possible outcomes I can imagine:

1. The creature is gone in the field but reappears on the other side as if the field had not been there. 
   If so, then what happens if the creature would hit someone or something within the field? Will it just fly through?
2. The creature stops moving on the first field in the antimagic field and returns there when the field is gone.

*This question is not about whether you can throw a creature through a whole antimagic field. I can think of multiple ways for the creature to have enough momentum to traverse the field, for example throw it off a cliff and then there is a Antimagic Field half way towards the ground because a wizard is standing on a little ledge.*

Comment: May need some clarification here into what you think an antimagic field actually affects (see also: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143751/how-are-fiends-celestials-dragons-etc-affected-by-the-antimagic-field-spell/143752#143752)

Comment: @PJRZ I had read a different answer which states that creatures like celestials would be affected by the antimagic field if they are generated by the conjure celestial spell. Please have a look, I linked the source in the question.

Comment: @NautArch I removed the object part, it is optional Also I tried to focus a bit more on the problem in the question. I hope it is better now. The problem that I have with an example is that I don't want to focus on how you get the creature to pass through the field. There are ways to do so, I mentioned one, but they all are not situations you would just encounter. So I don't want the setup to distract from the actual interaction that I am interested in.

Comment: @findusl: It is clearer now, but I'm still not sure what you mean in point 2, where you talk about a creature that has "parts that are non magical like an undead with bones".

Comment: @NautArch I made one big fat question that is the main one that I would like an answer to. There are still small ones around that I would hope to also get an answer to, but if not I will ask them separately.

Comment: @PJRZ I see, I was under the wrong impression there was a spell version of Create undead that require concentration. My bad. I will remove that part, it is not essential to the question.

Comment: In light of the answer provided by Darth Pseudonym, perhaps it would be best to rephrase the question as "into an antimagic field" versus "through an antimagic field," but I can also see arguments for leaving it as-is in case someone wants to find the question as was originally asked. Just a thought.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### It stops inside the field.

This can be answered by the *antimagic field* spell itself.

> **Creatures and Objects.** A creature or object summoned or created by magic temporarily winks out of existence in the sphere. Such a creature instantly reappears once the space the creature occupied is no longer within the sphere.

Once a summoned creature gets winked out, the one and only condition for reappearance is "*the space the creature occupied*" -- past tense -- "*is no longer within the sphere*".

There is no real wiggle room here.  What space was the creature was occupying when it winked out? Is that space still inside the AMF? It doesn't matter how fast the creature was moving or in what direction, the space it was occupying is what it is.

The real question, if you ask me, is this: When and if the creature/object reappears, does it retain its momentum, or does it reappear at rest with respect to the ground?  (My personal answer is: It retains its momentum, because that's *hilarious*.)

Comment: I probably know the answer to the extra question: DnD 5e is not a physics simulation 

Comment: Interesting argument about the only way something can reappear.

Comment: @findusl Edited to add my answer to the real question.

Comment: Spells only do what they say, and "wink out of existence" doesn't say anything about removing momentum or stopping the creature. So, I think it's safe to say that the "Speedy Thing Goes In, Speedy Thing Comes Out" option is RAW.

Comment: @AgentPaper I disagree that it's clearly RAW to do it that way, though it's my preferred option. You could equally argue that the prior movement was due to a spell or action that is no longer happening, and since AMF doesn't say the creature winks back in under the exact same circumstances as it left, there's no RAW indication that it *does* continue moving.

Comment: Support for your preferred answer for the extra question is the way it would make most sense to work: The creature time travels from when it winks out, to the moment it reappears. That would also mean it didn't percieve anything that happened in between as happening, which seems consistent with the intent.